# setCustomValidity is not a function

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, aura

why this error keep coming?

```
var num1 = 1 var num2 = 2 var inputCmp = component.find('Username');

if(num1 < num2){ inputCmp.setCustomValidity("John Doe is already registered"); }
```

Comment: Do you have more than one component with that "Username" Id? If so`inputCmp` will be a collection - see [.set and .setCustomValidity not working for two checkboxes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263511/set-and-setcustomvalidity-not-working-for-two-checkboxes).